# Hyperbolic groups and residual finiteness

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

The existence of a hyperbolic group which is not residually finite is (to my knowledge) an open question. Is there any reason to suspect that all hyperbolic groups are residually finite, perhaps some hope that existing techniques for showing residual finiteness can be extended to all hyperbolic groups? Alternatively, is it generally suspected that hyperbolic groups which are not residually finite exist but techniques to construct them are unknown?

Comment: I guess you mean the existence of hyperbolic groups which are not residually finite?

Comment: Yes, edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that there is a general belief in either direction (well, I heard some say so in the direction of the existence of non-RF hyperbolic groups, but I don't share this impression). However, I think that if it's ever true that all hyperbolic groups are RF, this doesn't follow from "existing techniques".

Comment: Here are generalities you may know. Sela proved that every torsion-free hyperbolic group is Hopfian, and being Hopfian is a necessary condition for being RF (by Malcev). Gromov more or less conjectured that not all hyperbolic groups are RF in his monograph on hyperbolic groups. If all hyperbolic groups are RF, then it follows from a theorem of Olshanskii that for every non-elementary hyperbolic group $G$, every finite group embeds in a finite quotient of $G$ ("S-finite-Q-universality"). So RF for hyperbolic groups means that there really are **lots** of finite quotients. [contd.]

Comment: [contd.] Assuming that every hyperbolic group is RF, here are two more corollaries: every hyperbolic group is virtually torsion-free (Kapovich-Wise); every quasi-convex subgroup of every hyperbolic group is separable (Agol-Groves-Manning). This latter would show that if hyperbolic groups are all RF, then we have **even more** finite quotients. Finally, some techniques have been ruled out for constructing non-residually finite hyperbolic groups, e.g. in [this nice paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05797) by Alan Logan.

Comment: AFAIK, the general belief is that there are non-RF hyperbolic groups. Maybe we even have a technique for proving their existence, it is just unclear where to look. Maybe one can use some probabilistic arguments (according to Gromov, "it's just on the edge, at the density 1/2.

Comment: Regarding extending existing techniques: One common method of proving residual finiteness of hyperbolic groups is cubulation. For example, one-relator groups with torsion and small cancellation groups were shown to be residually finite by proving that a finite index subgroup acts on a CAT(0) cubical complex in a specific (special...) way. However, cubulated hyperbolic groups are always linear, and M. Kapovich proved that there are non-linear hyperbolic groups. Therefore, cubulation cannot be extended to all hyperbolic groups.

Comment: There are also many hyperbolic linear groups which cannot be cubulated, for instance complex hyperbolic lattices by a result of P. Py (see https://zbmath.org/1294.32007 , https://zbmath.org/7094914)